PDF is truncated after printing with PdfiumViewer in landscape orientation
I tested PdfiumViewer to print a PDF file in landscape orientation.
https://github.com/pvginkel/PdfiumViewer
In the printed-out paper, some content is truncated.
The testing code is below.
public void PrintPDF(string printerName, string filePath)
{
    // Create the printer settings for our printer
    var printerSettings = new PrinterSettings
    {
        PrinterName = printerName
    };
    printerSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;

    // Create our page settings for the paper size selected
    var pageSettings = new PageSettings(printerSettings)
    {
        Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0),
    };

    // Now print the PDF document
    using (var document = PdfDocument.Load(filePath))
    {
        using (var printDocument = document.CreatePrintDocument())
        {
            printDocument.PrinterSettings = printerSettings;
            printDocument.DefaultPageSettings = pageSettings;
            printDocument.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
            printDocument.Print();
        }
    }
}

Has anyone encountered the similar problem?
Your advice is much appreciated.

If the PDF is being truncated when printing in landscape orientation with PdfiumViewer, here are some potential solutions and considerations to help resolve the issue:

Check Page Size and Scaling
pageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("A4", 827, 1169); // Example for A4 size in landscape

Adjust Margins
pageSettings.Margins = new Margins(10, 10, 10, 10); // Small margins

Modify PrintDocument Settings
printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;

Printer Properties: Check the printer properties dialog to ensure there are no default settings that might interfere with the print job, such as auto-scaling or fit-to-page options.


Example Revised Code
Here’s an example of how your code could be modified to incorporate some of these suggestions:
    public void PrintPDF(string printerName, string filePath)
{
  
     // Create the printer settings for our printer
    var printerSettings = new PrinterSettings
    {
        PrinterName = printerName
    };
    
    // Create our page settings for the paper size selected
    var pageSettings = new PageSettings(printerSettings)
    {
        Margins = new Margins(10, 10, 10, 10), // Adjust margins if necessary
        Landscape = true,
        PaperSize = new PaperSize("A4", 827, 1169) // Ensure the paper size matches
    };

    // Now print the PDF document
    using (var document = PdfDocument.Load(filePath))
    {
        using (var printDocument = document.CreatePrintDocument())
        {
            printDocument.PrinterSettings = printerSettings;
            printDocument.DefaultPageSettings = pageSettings;
            printDocument.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
            printDocument.Print();
        }
    }
}


I tested your code and PDF is printed in portrait orientation.

printDocument.PrintPage += (sender, e) =>
{
e.PageSettings.Landscape = true;
};
///Add this piece of code just before printDocument.Print();

Note: This event handler explicitly sets the Landscape property of the PageSettings to true for each page being printed, ensuring that the document prints in landscape mode.

If I remove this code, it can print as Landscape: PaperSize = new PaperSize("A4", 827, 1169). But it's still truncated. I may give up pdfiumviewer and use other printing tools
